# 'It' and 'this' difference

Tags: pronouns

Which one I should use in the following context? Are they both grammatical?

> **A**: The government has planted one million trees in the city. **It** will improve the air quality in the environment.
>
> **B**: The government has planted one million trees in the city. **This** will improve the air quality in the environment.

Answer (score 1):

I think Version B sounds better than Version A, but Version A could be reworded to:

> The government has planted one million trees in the city. **They** will improve the air quality in the environment.

Here, the plural pronoun **they** refers to trees (as opposed to the singular pronoun *it*, which presumably refers to the act itself).

I think the sentence reads a little awkwardly when a singular pronoun follows the phrase "one million trees."

Comment: Does using 'it' in version A make the sentence ungrammatical?

Comment: @user282192 - What will improve the air quality? The government, or the million trees?

Comment: I want to refer back to the previous whole sentence, which is an act. Can I use 'it' to refer back a whole sentence?

Comment: @user282192 - You really should stick with Version B then.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/writing/it-this-and-that-in-paragraphs

Comment: ^That site says that both 'it' and 'this' can be used to refer back whole sentences and clauses. 'This' highlights the information referred to much more strongly than 'it'. So here is a sentence from the site, which is written using this. Can I also use 'It' there? C: More and more people are discovering that Tai Chi is one of the most valuable forms of exercise. 'This/it' has led to a big demand for classes. (If it is right, then why can't I use it in my sentence 'The government has decided to plant one million trees in the city. 'It/this' will improve the air quality in the environment.'?)

Comment: @user282192 - Have you noticed that I’m dodging the question on whether or not the “it” would be grammatical? Lots of sentences are grammatical, yet they still exhibit slipshod writing. Yes, “it” can refer back to an entire sentence – but your example is not a good example of it. I’ll ask it again: _What will improve the air quality? The government, or the million trees?_ In contrast: _The government has said a million trees will be planted in the city. It will issue more details in a statement tomorrow._ Oh, and shame for putting your research in these comments instead of in your question.

Answer (score 1):

They are both grammatical. However, the only sentence of the two that is not capable of a complete misinterpretation is the one that uses *this*.

> The government has planted one million trees in the city. ***This*** will improve the air quality in the environment.

The use of *this* can actually refer to two different things:

1. The planting of one million trees in the city.
2. The government planting one million trees in the city.

So, there is a small degree of ambiguity, but the essential meaning remains the same.

---

In contrast, the use of *it* can be far more ambiguous:

> The government has planted one million trees in the city. ***It*** will improve the air quality in the environment.

1. The planting of one million trees in the city.
2. The government planting one million trees in the city.

The first two interpretations mirror that of *this*. However, there's a third interpretation that changes everything:

3. The government.

In short, the following is a possible interpretation:

> The government has planted one million trees in the city. [***The government***] will improve the air quality in the environment.

It would be read in the same way as:

> The government has planted one million trees in the city. ***It*** will plant a further two million trees in the countryside.

---

So, while there is a subtle difference in interpretation as to the referent of *this*, there can be a much greater difference in interpretation if *it* is used. (*This* can't be mistaken as referring to the government in the same way that *it* can.)

If you want to avoid a possibly significant misinterpretation, then *this* is the better pronoun.